# serving static files on sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm working on a Sinatra app for the first time and am stumbling into an issue with serving a javascript asset.

I am following the Sinatra convention of putting the static files in “public” folder and it works locally but when we create a Docker image, we get a 404 while this works with localhost.

I see where I can set the public_folder which I have tried like this:
http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

but still 404'ing. Is there a way to get the top-level object and ask it where it expects the public_folder to be (like Rails.env)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `settings` object.

```
irb(main):001:0> require "sinatra"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> settings.public_folder
=> "/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/public"
```

This allows you to create a route which returns the path, something like this

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    settings.public_folder
end
```

Without more information I would guess that your public folder points to a wrong directory inside your docker because the project `:root` points to a different directory that what you expect.